# My Connection Code is not working why?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, connection

why is it my Connection code not working? I have everything right password,user, and the host and the driver but why is it not working??

```
 import java.sql.*;

public class Connection {

    public  String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Testdb";
    public String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    public String user = "root";
    public String pass = "123192";

    public void JdbcConnection(){

        try{
            Class.forName(driver);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try{
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell from the code alone. What's the error you're seeing?

Comment: Does it throws any exception?

Comment: And what's the exact error reported?

Comment: the error is in Connection con it's not working

Comment: @user962206 Why don't you paste your stack trace so we can better help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the name of your class (it must not a `Connection` especially when you import the `java.sql.*`) and you need to specify the username and password while obtaining a connection.

```
public class TestConnection {
   ....
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
}
```

Comment: @user962206 - You have to change the name of class.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that "`Connection con`" should be of type `java.sql.Connection`, but since your own class is called `Connection`, your code thinks you are making a reference to that instead of `java.sql.Connection`. You can disambiguate the type of `con` by using the full class name like so:

```
try{
    java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```